# NetCDF Time Series to Feature Layer in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, netcdf

I have a daily timeseries nc file that I am trying to convert to a feature layer in ArcMap. Below is how I am selecting the values, which gives me a empty table, how can this be fixed in ArcMap 10.7?

[image]

Empty Table

[image]

Desired output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I had to first use "NetCDF to table view" to convert the nc file into a table, and then do a spatial join to the shapefile.

[image]